# jQuery-File-Upload: duplicateImage not working

Tags: jquery-file-upload

The following works for me, the image is re-sized to 800x600 and stored on the server.

```
jQuery ->
  $('#fileupload').fileupload
    processQueue: [
      {
        action: 'loadImage'
        fileTypes: /^image\/(gif|jpeg|png)$/
        maxFileSize: 20000000
      }
      {
        action: 'resizeImage'
        maxWidth: 800
        maxHeight: 600
      }
      { action: 'saveImage' }
    ]
   add: (e, data) ->
    $.blueimp.fileupload.prototype.options.add.call(this, e, data)
```

However, if I add a subsequent duplicateImage action it fails.

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload
    processQueue: [
      {
        action: 'loadImage'
        fileTypes: /^image\/(gif|jpeg|png)$/
        maxFileSize: 20000000
      }
      {
        action: 'resizeImage'
        maxWidth: 800
        maxHeight: 600
      }
      { action: 'saveImage' }
      { action: 'duplicateImage'}
      {
          action: 'resizeImage'
          maxWidth: 1280
          maxHeight: 1024
      }
      {action: 'saveImage'}
    ]
   add: (e, data) ->
    $.blueimp.fileupload.prototype.options.add.call(this, e, data)
```

Here is the error I am getting in my JavaScript console.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Clicking on the error link brings me to the following section of code in jquery.fileupload

```
82 return that.processActions[settings.action].call(
83   that,
84   data,
85   settings
86 );
```

In case I am missing a dependency, my application.js (Rails app) looks as follows

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic-plus
//= require jquery-fileupload/vendor/tmpl
//= require_tree .
```

How do I fix this? Also, how do I rename the re-sized files? I guess at the moment they will just over-write each other? I see the advise [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Upload-multiple-resolutions-of-one-image-with-multiple-resize-options) is to somehow do this in processActions but I cannot figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the following, as per [this guide.](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Upload-multiple-resolutions-of-one-image-with-multiple-resize-options)

```
$.blueimp.fileupload::processActions.duplicateImage = (data, options) ->
  if data.canvas
    data.files.push data.files[data.index]
  data
```